# How exactly does Spring inject properties when annotating with @Value?

Tags: java, spring, properties, annotations

I've been wondering: how exactly does Spring inject properties when using the `@Value` annotation? What's the mechanism behind this that checks if a field has the annotation? Is it using reflection and some class that finds all annotated classes and creates an instance of them injecting the property, or is it doing it some other way? I know annotation processing would only be used during compilation and will not change the code, so what's happening behind the scenes here really...?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`@Value`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation type has the [`@Retention(value=RUNTIME)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#RUNTIME) annotation, which means that the information is available at runtime (i.e. using reflection).

A `BeanPostProcessor`, in particular the [`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) can check for the presence of this annotation on fields, methods or constructors of a bean after instantiation.

Comment: So, if I'm getting this right, this will only work, if a bean is autowired or defined in context? The BeanPostProcessor will create an instance of the class using reflection and set the value for the respective field...? So, it's all reflection and nothing else, right?

Comment: The bean is created by another class, a BeanPostProcessor (as the name implies) is only used to modify beans after instantiation.  But otherwise indeed no other magic is needed :)

Comment: And indeed, it has to be a Spring bean (either defined in XML or through annotations).  It doesn't have to be autowired, the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor handles @Autowired/@Inject as well as @Value annotations.

Answer (score 1):

If annotation-config feature is on then each time Spring instantiates a bean it goes thru all of its fields and methods and checks if they are annotated with one of Spring supported annotations using reflection.