# Kotlin Spring boot @Value annotation process

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

```
@Value("\${datasource.host}")
private val host: String = ""
```

I wrote the following code in KOTLIN and it worked fine.

I don't understand how the `host` was injected into the `host`. 
In my knowledge, the value should not be injected because the `host` variable is val.

How does this code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Spring is magical!

For a Kotlin property, `val` doesn't necessarily mean that the property is constant.  (It's not an exact equivalent of Java `final` here.)  It simply means that there's a `get()` method but no `set()` method.

That leaves open the possibility for the value to change some other way.  (For example, the property could have a custom getter which returned different values.)

I'm not sure quite how Spring works its magic; it may be able to set the property's backing field directly, or it may create a hidden subclass which can.  In any case, it's perfectly capable of setting `val` properties.  (You can also see this in Hibernate.)

Comment: I heard that @Value uses reflection, can `val` be changed to reflection?
ref) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319122/how-exactly-does-spring-inject-properties-when-annotating-with-value